# AssertionError: expected false to equal true

Tags: angularjs, protractor, cucumber, e2e-testing, cucumberjs

Here is the code:

```
this.Then(/^I click to the next button on the edit page$/,function(callback) {
    targetPO.getEditNextButton().isPresent().then(function(){
        targetPO.getEditNextButton().click().then(callback);
    });
})
```

I got the:

> AssertionError: expected false to equal true

error. I can not find any useful tutorial, only saint tales.

What is the reason for the error?

Here is the getEditNextButton() function:

```
function getEditNextButton() {
    return element(by.id(selectors.editNextButton));
}
```

Comment: On which line does it fail? There is no `expect()` call in the posted code. Thanks.

Comment: have you made any assertion inside `getEditNextButton` method?

Comment: Hi All!

Here is the getEditNextButton function

function getEditNextButton() {
        return element(by.id(selectors.editNextButton));
    }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the way you are calling the function. It can be solved in two ways:
1) Either from **function getEditNextButton()**, you remove **'element'** in the return ***element***(by.id(selectors.editNextButton));

 
or

2) Since, by calling **getEditNextButton()**  function,  you are returning  'element(by.id(...)' .
 So, You should  remove ***element.*** from 'element.getEditNextButton().click().then(callback);'

Comment: HI Arpitjain!

I repaired my description,with the targetPO in the step.js.
I was confussed,but I treid to remove element from the return statement,but I got the same error,I have no idea.